# Word (adjective) to describe a harsh sound

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives, american-english, sounds

Context: My brother just played a video with loud screeching noises in the background about 5 feet from me as I was reading a pleasant book. I turned to chastise him, exclaiming,

> "John! Turn that off! That sounds is so _______."

I couldn't find the proper word. *Discordant*, *biting*, *harsh* aren't quite right. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't an adjective, and it doesn't *exactly* fit into your example sentence, but what I immediately thought of was [**cacophony**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cacophony).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : harsh or jarring sound : DISSONANCE sense 2
> *specifically* : harshness in the sound of words or phrases
>
> DISSONANCE sense 2:
> **2** : a mingling of sounds that strike the ear harshly : a mingling of discordant sounds
> *especially, music* : a clashing or unresolved musical interval or chord

To paraphrase your sentence:

> John! Turn off that cacophony!

---

As was mentioned in a comment, there is an adjectival form of this word:

> John! Turn that off! That sound is so cacophonous.

Comment: Or `that sound is so cacophonous`.

Comment: @jason Thanks for this reply! I considered it earlier, but dismissed it-offhand because I had imprecise definition on my mind. Thankfully, your post of the definition forced me to revisit it!

Comment: @alwayslearning Yes! Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

***[​Grating:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grating)***

> A grating sound is unpleasant and annoying.

also

***[Deafening](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deafening)*** is often used for loud, annoying sounds/noises:

> extremely loud:
>
> - The music was deafening.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

An adjective I remember reading in this context is ***raucous***.

> "John! Turn that off! That sounds so ***raucous***."

ODO:

> [**raucous**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/raucous)   ADJECTIVE
>   Making or constituting a disturbingly
>   harsh and loud noise.
>
> ‘She threw the keys back and forth, causing them to fill the air with raucous noise.’
>
> ‘It stopped dead in the middle of the road with a raucous screech of
>   the brakes.’