# Adjective to describe a 'hurtful kind of art/music'

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the proper adjective that describes some kind of music or art that is considered very inferior and not appealing to the ear (for music) or to the eye (for art)?

Comment: I trust there won't be a list of synonyms for 'third rate', 'substandard' etc or 'offensive' and synonyms. These would be far too hypernymic. Words at least nuancing music / the arts in general are suitable.

Comment: You mean like Pop Music?    Every new generation eventually finds an  "new" expression of art that is part original, mostly  derivative, and quite often  a complete poke in the eye of the older generation. ...who have ignored the social significance.

Comment: hurtful has two meanings.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? [Word {adjective} to describe a harsh sound](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472328/word-adjective-to-describe-a-harsh-sound/472338#472338)

Comment: Needs clarification. "Not appealing" is not the same as "hurtful". Music might be uninteresting, edgy, actively discordant and repelling (to some people or to everyone), or offensive on non-musical grounds (e.g. made by immoral people).

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_: I was into "underground rock" back when I was a rebellious young Turk. 20 years later it almost seemed to me they'd specifically *invented* rap music to get up my nose, poke me in the eye, and generally discomfit me. Eventually I found a few rap songs that I liked, but it took quite some searching! If I want to listen to music today, though, I just put Flaming Lips [*In The Arms Of Cocaine*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQefTDPRvco) on auto-repeat until the feeling goes away (*eventually* - there's no hurry! :)

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ indeed, is *The Garden of Earthly Delights* by Hieronymus Bosch "considered very inferior"?

Comment: No reason **painful** couldn't be used metaphorically for anything you dislike, whereas *hurtful* implies the intent to hurt.

Answer (score 3):

> **cacophonous**  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cacophonous)
> having an unpleasant mixture of sounds:
> *We woke up to the cacophonous sound of birds.
>
> The restaurant is a cacophonous, high-ceilinged room.*

Comment: But what about for visual art?

Answer (score 2):

For the appealing in art forms, we have:

> **aesthetic**, *n.* and *adj.*
> **B. adj. 4.** Of a thing: in accordance with principles of artistic beauty or taste; giving or designed to give pleasure through beauty;
> of pleasing appearance.

For the unappealing, we have the opposite:

> **unaesthetic**, *adj.*
>  (UN- *prefix<sup>1</sup>* 1.)

<sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I offer (from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grotesque))

> **grotesque**
> strange and unpleasant, especially in a silly or slightly frightening way

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotesque) has

> **Grotesque** has come to be used as a general adjective for the strange, mysterious, magnificent, fantastic, hideous, ugly, incongruous, unpleasant, or disgusting, and thus is often used to describe weird shapes and distorted forms such as Halloween masks. **In art, performance, and literature**, however, grotesque may also refer to something that simultaneously invokes in an audience a feeling of uncomfortable bizarreness as well as sympathetic pity.

Comment: In the visual arts (and perhaps also in music) it can also—and this is more common in theoretical writings—refer to mostly (organic) decorative patterns, so this might not be the best adjective for the OP's use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "hurtful" but it sounds like "kitsch" is more or less what you have in mind.

**kitsch**

*noun:*

> art, objects, or design considered to be in poor taste
> because of excessive garishness or sentimentality, but sometimes
> appreciated in an ironic or knowing way. *"the lava lamp is an example
> of sixties kitsch"*

*adjective*:

> considered to be in  poor taste but appreciated in an ironic
> or knowing way.

Answer (score 0):

[Dissonant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dissonant) describes a non-harmonic combination of musical notes.

[Discordant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discordant) should do the same for colors, although not exclusive to this context.